# How much area to feed the colony of snails?

Tags: husbandry, food, mollusca

Snails are good source of proteins. How much area should I have to provide food for the colony of snails producing about 100kg of "meat" every year?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

we actually bred snails for quite a while on 6 boxes of 1 square meter. I never weighed the annual production, but these 6 square meter were by far sufficient. We actually stopped breeding snails because of "overproduction".

They were fed on our vegetables garbage. The problem with snails is not so much the insufficient area to feed them, but more the moisturized environment they require. They love water! We live in Belgium, where there is an abundance of rain. If you life in a dry area, keeping snails might be challenging.